# How do you authorize HTTP POST & GET request with Google Admin SDK?

Tags: powershell, coldfusion, google-admin-sdk

I support an organization of 200,000+ users.  My current skill set, and the tools at my disposal include PowerShell and ColdFusion.  Both can be utilized to make HTTP POST & GET requests.

I created a Google API service account for my organization.  I *think* I know what the public key is, and I believe I've downloaded the private key.  In this PowerShell example, I'm trying to see if this particular user is set to require a password change at next logon:

```
$request="https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/USER@DOMAIN.COM?fields=changePasswordAtNextLogin&key={MY PUBLIC KEY?}"
$cert=Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath "C:\PATH\PRIVATEKEY.P12"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $request -Method GET -Certificate $cert
```

When I run this, it'll ask for the password of the certificate, I supply it, but I still get "...The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized..."

I cannot figure out Google's documentation.  Can somebody please help me figure out how to perform administrative functions against Google Accounts in my domain?  I need to do it like a "service" account...

What do I need to read?  Where do I go from here?  Does anyone have a good example?

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. I've no example to give, but maybe you are interested in a tool like GAM (https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/)

Comment: GAM didn't suffice for our purposes.  We are investigating several options, including ASP.net & C#. I would really like to learn how to modify a Google Apps account with a manual HTTP POST request.  I need a quick and dirty example that I can glean off of, if anybody has one.

Comment: There is a official API client for C# (https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/csharp/latest/). There is no quick and dirty example for OAuth2, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache as web server you could evaluate the module auth_openidc. 
This enables you to authenticate at webserverlevel. In the application you get the server variable remote_user if the login was successful. See https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc.
A php example can be found in the wiki of this project at https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/wiki. 
This is an example of OpenID Connect, see http://openid.net/connect/faq/.